# Should /dist/ be included in jest tests?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I have a React typescript project where I have `foo.test.ts` alongside `foo.ts` within a `/src/` directory that is built into a `/dist/` directory. By default, typescript compiles `foo.test.ts` to `foo.test.js` within the `/dist/` directory. When I run tests with Jest, it will test on the `/src/` Typescript test as well as the `/dist/` JavaScript version. Is there a reason to **not** exclude `*.test.ts` from `tsconfig.json` so that only one copy of the test exists - the `/src/` one? Or inversely, should the Jest (somehow) ignore the `/src/` version and only run tests on the `/dist/` version?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of supporting both, there is likely little to no value in doing so. Wether you test the `/src/*.test.ts` or `/dist/*.test.js` is mostly up to preference. However, there are benefits to using `*.ts` over `*.js`.

I see you are using *Jest* for tests, therefore I will assume you are utilizing [ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest). The value of *ts-jest* is that it is a "jest transformer ... that lets you use Jest to test projects written in typescript"; therefore, you don't need to manually transpile your `*.ts` into `*.js` to test the code.

On the contrary, if you were to not use *ts-jest* or want to test the `*.js`, you'll have to transpile the code before every run of the testsuite. If you do not, or there are stale files within the `/dist/*`, then it may result in unexpected test suite results.

Personally, I would suggest ignoring the `/dist` directory, and using ts-jest to run your typescript files as it is much simpler. To do so, in your `jest.config.js`, ignore the path with the property `testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/dist/']` ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring)) or update your test match to only do `.ts` `testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts']`